How to create preview deployment instance for each pull request ( Preview Mode ) in Azure for NextJS application?
We deployed NextJS application with Docker on Azure and we have 3 branches:

Dev : for development
Staging: for pre-production
Main: for production

For each new feature we create a branch feature and we push changes. However, we want the stakeholders to see the live changes for this feature before merging it to dev branch.
In Vercel  and Github, this feature is available :


This is our pipeline when we merge a pull request to dev branch:
trigger:
  - dev

variables:
  dockerRegistryServiceConnection: "xxx"
  imageRepository: "xxx"
  containerRegistry: "xxx"
  dockerfilePath: "$(Build.SourcesDirectory)/Dockerfile.prod"
  tag: "$(Build.BuildId)"
  vmImageName: "ubuntu-latest"

pool:
  vmImage: ubuntu-latest

stages:
  - stage: Install
    displayName: "Install"
    jobs:
      - job: InstallJob
        displayName: "Install Node.js and Dependencies"
        steps:
          - task: NodeTool@0
            inputs:
              versionSpec: "20.x"
            displayName: "Install Node.js"
          - script: |
              npm install
            displayName: "Install Node.js and Dependencies"

  - stage: UnitComponentTests
    displayName: "Run Unit and Component Tests"
    jobs:
      - job: UnitComponnentTestsJob
        displayName: "Run Unit  and Component Tests"
        steps:
          - script: |
              npm install
              npm run test
            displayName: "Run Unit and Component Tests"

  - stage: E2ETests
    displayName: "Run E2E Tests"
    jobs:
      - job: E2ETestsJob
        displayName: "Run E2E Tests"
        steps:
          - script: |
              npm install
              npx playwright install
              npm run test-e2e
            displayName: "Run E2E Tests"

  - stage: Build
    displayName: Build
    jobs:
      - job: Build
        displayName: Build
        pool:
          vmImage: $(vmImageName)
        steps:
          - task: Docker@2
            displayName: Build and push an image to container registry
            inputs:
              command: buildAndPush
              repository: $(imageRepository)
              dockerfile: $(dockerfilePath)
              buildContext: "./"
              containerRegistry: $(dockerRegistryServiceConnection)
              tags: |
                $(tag)
                latest


I want to have the same file that run for each pull request. After we merge the pull request, the deployment instance should be deleted.

Where do you want to display the information or link of the preview deployment instance? Where is the Git repository of the pull request hosted? What CI/CD platform are you using to run the build and deployment jobs?

Hi @BrightRan-MSFT,
We use DevOps for hosting the repository.
We use Azure App Service
We use Azure Pipelines
We use Docker + Nextjs.

So, you want the pull request of git repository in Azure DevOps also can show the similar or same information like as that on the pull request of GitHub repository? @AlaEddineMenai

Not necessarily displaying information. But the goal is where and how to deploy changes for each pull request whatever the method you suggest. Just some tips to start with.

You can try to set the Build validation check on the branch policies of Dev branch. For  more details, see my answer below. @AlaEddineMenai

You can try to set the Build validation check on the branch policies of Dev branch. On this check, you can select the existing pipeline.
With the Build validation:

Every time when you create a new pull request that the target branch is Dev, the pipeline set on the Build validation will be triggered to run for the pull request.

After the pull request has created and is Active (not Abandoned or Completed), every time when new commits pushed to the source branch, the new commits are automatically synced to the pull request, the pipeline set on the Build validation will be triggered to run for the pull request.



